# Unusual condition (* ((uint64_t *) buf) == NEG)

Tags: c

The case is that i'm studying a code i found on the internet which caught my attention, is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#define NEG ~0x0LL

void ITOC(int8_t *vec, int n)
{
    int8_t *p = vec;
    for(; n; n /= 10) *p++ = n % 10;
}

void ncmp(int8_t *buf, int y)
{
    int tmp, i = 0;

    for (; y ; y/=10)
    {
        tmp =  y % 10;
        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            if(buf[i] == tmp && buf[i] != -1)
            {
                buf[i] = -1;
                break;
            }
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    int8_t buf[8];
    int y = 21 ,z = 60, n = 1260;
    *((uint64_t*) buf) = NEG;

    ITOC(buf, n);
    ncmp(buf, y);
    ncmp(buf, z);

    if( *((uint64_t*) buf) == NEG )
        printf("%d = %d * %d\n", n, y, z);

    return 0;
}
```

The part I do not understand this line:

```
if( *((uint64_t*) buf) == NEG )
```

If the variables have these values :

```
y = 21 z = 60 n = 1260
```

The condition is true but if these values contain:

```
y = 18 z = 81 n = 1458
```

In this case the first position **buf** is -1, if the **if** only compares the first position with **NEG** should also be true.

Can someone explain what happens?

Comment: The program has undefined behaviour because of type punning and aliasing violations.

Comment: Could it be that when it compiles, it replaces it exactly?

Comment: @KerrekSB: AFAIK it would be legal if `buf` were originally defined as a `uint64_t` though (then using `ITOC(&buf, ...)`), since type-punning to `char *` is legal.

Comment: @nneonneo: Quite right. If the program were originally correct, it would have been correct :-S

Answer (score 5):

I don't know where you found this code, but it certainly doesn't do what you think it does.

What you think it does is check some kind of multiplication.  Probably because it prints "n = y * z" at the end.  But what it actually does is it takes the digits of `n`, and remove the digits of `y` and `z`.  If all digits were removed, it prints that message.  So for example:

```
1111 = 11 * 11    true
1234 = 12 * 34    true
1500 = 10 * 50    true
1500 = 30 * 50    false
1458 = 18 * 81    false
1458 = 14 * 58    true
1458 = 45 * 18    true
```

Comment: as detected if all elements are -1, if only checks the first position of the array

Comment: @Tony The if checks a uint64_t which is 8 bytes long, so it is basically checking eight digits to see if every digit is -1.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your code you can see that

```
#define NEG ~0x0LL
```

Therefore `NEG` is the bit-wise inverse of `0x0LL`, which stands for (long long)0. Therefore, `NEG` is a long long with all bits set to one.

To understand your problem:

First, fix undefined behavior, allocate your `buf` (you need `stdlib.h`)

```
int8_t * buf;
buf = malloc(sizeof(* buf) * 8);
```

Then attach a debugger to `buf` with the expression `(uint64_t *)buf` and its view property as vector of uint8 (or equivalent from your debugger). This way you can actually see what's done with your variable and why it fails on those specific values.

[image: Sample debugger image]

Something to keep in mind: setting `buf[i]` is equivalent to setting the corresponding bits to `0xff` due to the data type.

Your code simply doesn't do what you *think* it does.

Comment: I need to understand because it is false with: y = 18 z = 81 n = 1458

Answer (score 0):

As said Nit, you are defining NEG as 64bits set to 1.
then what you do:

```
*((uint64_t*) buf) = NEG
```

so you are storing 64bits set to one in a 64bits of data pointed to by buf.

then, when you do the checking:

```
if( *((uint64_t*) buf) == NEG )
```

you compare 64bits pointed to by buf to 64 bits set to one.

what you seem to want to do is comparing only 8bits:

```
if( *((uint8_t*) buf) == (uint8_t)NEG )
```

I'm just reacting to:

```
, if the if only compares the first position
```

because the the if compares 64bits of data as asked by casting :)